# SWIFT: How to remove extra padding from a uilabel after using auto shrink?

Tags: swift

[image]
I have two labels of dynamic height that i want centered in a UICollectionViewCell. I added a detailContainerView centered on the cell and  added the two label using auto layout as shown below.

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        detailContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        detailContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor), // these labels are supposed to occupy the right half pf the cell
        detailContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
        detailContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 60)
        ])
```

Here are the labels:

```
 let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let nl = UILabel()
    nl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nl.textAlignment = .left
    nl.numberOfLines = 0
    nl.font = UIFont.actigage_systemFontOfSize(14)
    nl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    nl.textColor = .darkGray
    nl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    nl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
    return nl
}()

let categoryLabel: UILabel = {
    let nl = UILabel()
    nl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nl.textAlignment = .left
    nl.numberOfLines = 0
    nl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    nl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
    nl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    nl.font = UIFont.actigage_systemFontOfSize(12)
    return nl
}()
nameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(751, for: .vertical)
    nameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(751, for: .vertical)
```

And here are their constraints:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        categoryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailContainerView.topAnchor),
        categoryLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8),
        categoryLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
        categoryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 15)
        ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryLabel.bottomAnchor),
        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8),
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
        nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailContainerView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
```

Side Note: we don't want the labels to be larger than the cell size.

I can't figure out how to remove the extra space from the labels when the text auto shrinks. TIA :)

Comment: Remove the height constraint and let the height be dynamic according the height that the text has when shrunk?

Comment: Also, the compression resisntance and the hugging priority are only for elements inside stackviews, AFAIK.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I had to add a height less than constraint as i don't want the labels to be bigger than the cell.

Comment: Since the labels are inside the cell, they won't be bigger than the cell if you use top and bottom constraints (properly).

Comment: hey @Serdnad.. can you please expand on it a bit if possible. Should i add top/ bottom constraints to the detailContainerView with lower priority, cause i think i tried that as well.

Comment: I was building on what regina said about removing your height constraints. Since you're setting `categoryLabel`'s top anchor to its its containerView (a.k.a. its superview) and `nameLabels`'s bottom anchor to its containerView, you shouldn't need a fixed height constraint.

Comment: Oh, and instead of giving `detailContainerView` a centerY anchor, just give it a top and bottom constraint to the cell (that might be what regina meant)

Comment: But i need them centered so centerY anchor is needed for cases where the text is less so they remain centered.

Comment: If you are getting difficult to set constraints programmatically using NSLayoutConstraints then use https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit it is available in swift 3 and 4. you can easily set constraints programmatically and you can visualize what you are going to set constraints.